# How to copy or move to folder in Nautilus 2.30.1 like in Windows Explorer?

Tags: gui, nautilus

How to copy or move to folder in Nautilus 2.30.1 like in Windows Explorer? The only such options available in the context menu point to Home or Desktop, when I want to copy or move to another folder or drive.

Comment: You mean the "Send to" option in Explorer? Why would Nautilus necessarily have that?

Comment: And for those of us who, when they need to copy a file in Windows Explorer, start zsh in mintty: how do you copy a file in Windows Explorer?

Comment: This is a good question, I've been looking for this too. In Windows Explorer it is nice that you can right-click-drag to the destination and then choose between copy/move. Sure you can click on copy/cut and then paste at the destination, but that's a lot of clicking. I see an answer below says there is middle-click-drag in nautilus for the same effect, can't wait to try it.

Comment: @mohand: On the stackexchange sites it is custom to select one of the answers and to mark it as the accepted answer. Just click the checkmark below the ratings for an answer on the answer that you feel best answers the question. For instance, to select Janos' answer to drag with the middle mouse button, check the checkmark that appears under his rating when you hover the mouse there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "like in Windows Explorer"? Can you not select Copy / Move from the context menu (right-click menu) and then select Paste at the destination? If you want to add "shortcut" or "favorite" directories you can add them to the left-side pane, just as you had a list "Send to..." in Explorer. Dragging to these folders in the pane will Copy / Move your folder or files.

Answer (score 2):

You can also drag with the middle button, Nautilus will ask for copy/cut/link

Comment: not anymore in later versions of nautilus

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're pretty new to Linux. It takes a while to understand the principles (well, some distributions take longer to understand). Keep your head up!

After a while you'll see that the command line is pretty neat. You can copy/move files with the following commands.

Copy:

```
cp /path/to/file/you/want/to/copy/foo.txt /path/where/to/copy/it/foo.txt
```

Move:

```
mv /path/to/file/you/want/to/move/foo.txt /path/where/to/move/it/foo.txt
```

If you're interested, have a look at http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php.